# EOF in Windows command prompt doesn't terminate input stream

Tags: c, eof

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NEWLINE '\n'
#define SPACE ' '

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    int count = 0;

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch != NEWLINE  && ch != SPACE)
            count++;
    }
    printf("There are %d characters input\n" , count);

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

1. Everything works just fine, it will ignore spaces and newline and output the number of characters input to the screen (in this program I just treat comma, exclamation mark, numbers or any printable special symbol character like ampersand as character too) when I hit the EOF simulation which is `^z`.
2. But there's something wrong when I input this line to the program. For example I input this: `abcdefg^z`, which means I input some character before and on the same line as `^z`. Instead of terminating the program and print out total characters, the program would continue to ask for input.
3. The EOF terminating character input only works when I specify `^z` on a single line or by doing this: `^zabvcjdjsjsj`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is true in almost every terminal driver. You'll get the same behavior using Linux.

Your program isn't actually executing the loop until `\n` or `^z` has been entered by you  at the end of a line. The terminal driver is buffering the input and it hasn't been sent to your process until that occurs.

At the end of a line, hitting `^z` (or `^d` on Linux) does *not* cause the terminal driver to send EOF. It only makes it flush the buffer to your process (with no `\n`).

Hitting `^z` (or `^d` on Linux) at the start of a line is interpreted by the terminal as "I want to signal EOF".

You can observe this behavior if you add the following inside your loop:

```
printf("%d\n",ch);
```

Run your program:

```
$ ./test
abc                      <- type "abc" and hit "enter"
97
98
99
10
abc97                    <- type "abc" and hit "^z"
98
99
```

To better understand this, you have to realize that EOF is not a character. `^z` is a user command *for the terminal itself*. Because the terminal is responsible for taking user input and passing it to processes, this gets tricky and thus the confusion.

A way to see this is by hitting `^v` then hitting `^z` as input to your program.

`^v` is another terminal command that tells the terminal, "Hey, the next thing I type - don't interpret that as a terminal command; pass it to the process' input instead".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was so confused about printing things twice in the terminal and some other odd behaviors of my programs. So from your answer, I found that the first print is by the terminal driver, and the second is by my program and just after hitting the Enter key. thank you!!!!

Answer (score 5):

`^Z` is only translated by the console to an EOF signal to the program when it is typed at the start of a line. That's just the way that the Windows console works. There is no "workaround" to this behaviour that I know of.

Comment: Then why ^z is not counted as a character when i place it after a stream of characteres in one line??For example "abcdefg^z" only return me "There are 7 characters inpit" instead of 8 after i input ^z after that line.

Comment: @caramel23: I believe that the windows console simply ignores it and doesn't pass a character to the program being run. I don't know why this happens.