# Error in storing char as variable from user input

Tags: c, string, char, iteration

the idea is that i type in a sentence and store it as a string... then i can choose a letter and change it to a different letter

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char string[100];
    char newLetter;
    char oldLetter;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please enter your sentence : ");
    gets(string);

    printf("\n\nWord is : %s" , string );

    printf("\n\nTarget : ");
    scanf("%s", &oldLetter);
    printf("Replace with : ");
    scanf("%s", &newLetter);

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(string); i++) 
    { 
        if (string[i] == oldLetter)
        { 
            string[i] = newLetter; 
            break;
        } 
    }
    printf("\n\nWord is : %s" , string );

    system("PAUSE");   
    return 0;
}
```

any help in where I've gone wrong is appreciated

eg.
input could be - yellow lorry red lorry

then target - r

change to - t

output - yellow lotty ted lotty

Comment: Dangerous code. `scanf()` will keep scanning and the filling in data into memory until Uth finds a white-space character, but you gave it only a byte of memory.

Comment: Do not use gets() and scanf()!!

Comment: I would recommend you use the loop construct like this:

        while(string[i++] != '\0')
        {
            if(string[i] == oldLetter)
                string[i] = newLetter;
        }

Comment: @reza.safiyat That code will go out of bounds.

Comment: I may be wrong. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `%s` in the scanning of the two letters to `%c` and the code will run flawlessly.

Comment: it most probably still won't

Comment: Basically because of the new-line character `\n` left inside the stream, which will get recognized as the value to be scanned into the `newLetter`, if not discarded beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, since you are aiming to store a character to `char oldLetter` and `char newLetter` via `scanf`, you should be using the [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx) `%c` instead of the `%s`.

However, that won't be enough, because of the following: When you use functions like `scanf` or `gets`, you prompt user to input characters to the `stdin` stream. `stdin` stream is a buffered stream. You may think of it as a:

- Stream of river that you;
- drop characters into
- each character you drop remains inside the river
- until something takes them out

When `scanf` comes, and you type, say, `A` and then *press the enter key*, you put the following characters in the stream:

```
'A' '\n'
```

Where `\n` is the new-line character. With the enter key-press, you also inform the `scanf` that you're done. `scanf` then starts issuing the `stdin` buffer, let's see... `'A'`, a proper value for `%c` *character*. It takes that one out, leaves `\n` behind.

Then the next `scanf` comes, seeks for a `%c` in stream, finds the `\n` ready, takes that out. This is what you wouldn't want. Two ways to prevent it:

- use `fflush( stdin );` after the `scanf` calls, or
- use `while( getchar( ) != '\n' );` after the `scanf` calls

to dismiss/discard the remaining characters in the buffer.

And get rid of that `break;` if you want to replace each occurrence and not just the first one.

Comment: No. `fflush( stdin )` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @self. Dude, OP uses `scanf( "%c", ... )` to get a character from standard input, and you make `fflush( stdin )` a problem? One cannot please everyone, but hey, I tried, and offered two alternatives there. Second one also isn't perfect, I'd say `while ( stdin->_cnt ) getchar( );` would pretty much be perfect, but that would just be an overkill, for the reason at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: Also `while( getchar( ) != '\n' );` should check for != EOF.

Comment: Because you don't check for EOF and might miss it, causing an inf loop.

Comment: @self. That doesn't explain anything. Explain me why `EOF` should not be missed when each line is terminated by a `'\n'`.

Comment: I'm going to let you figure that out by yourself.

Comment: @self. Such a decent help, man, you're incredible. I have to say, *some people are weird.*

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Cool avatar picture.

Comment: `scanf("%c",...)` is a correct, standard method to read a character. `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard and may crash the program.  I don't know why you attempt to draw some sort of conclusion about the validity of the latter , based on the former.

Comment: To actually answer the question about EOF,  if `getchar()` returns EOF then it will fail to compare equal to `\n`, so the loop will never terminate.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `fflush( stdin )` won't lead into any crash, provided that you are using MSVC or possibly some other compilers as well. In case it leads into a problem, one may always use the alternative method provided.

Comment: and what if you aren't using MSVC or possibly some other compilers? Just use the standard method the first time, then we don't have to worry about what compiler is being used.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The answer of that question is already there, making that question is absolutely redundant.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ... as for the `EOF` check, I was unable to find out even a single example case where extending the `while` condition to make a check for `EOF` does any help.

Comment: Type some characters then press Ctrl-D  (or Ctrl-Z if you're in Windows) instead of pressing Enter.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `EOF` check doesn't do any help about it, or any bad. With or without; I need one further enter key-press to advance out of the `while`, when I append my lines with `CTRL + Z`.

Comment: Something's wrong with your terminal if pressing keys after EOF makes any difference

Comment: @MattMcNabb This answer says *no* to that claim of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373799/2736228

Comment: The "accepted" answer to that question explains , if you press Ctrl-Z but it wasn't at the start of the line, then EOF is not sent (just a buffer flush). So, type some characters and then press Ctrl-Z twice.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why in quotes... With the `EOF` check, I type `asd` then; **(a)** `Ctrl + Z` then `Ctrl + Z` then press Enter key 2 times, **(b)** `Ctrl + Z` then Enter once then `Ctrl + Z` again and Enter once again to break out of the `while`. Without the `EOF` check, `asd` then; **(c)** same as the **a**, **(d)** I press the enter key once more at the end to break out of the `while`. So -at best- the difference it makes is just one more Enter-key key-press. Is this it? Is this really the reason for all this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right, or you can do it wrong and hope that the person doesn't enter the right series of keystrokes or pipe in a file that doesn't end in newline, to break it ... up to you