# Scanf more values C

Tags: c, scanf

i need help with short Code in C. I must read floats on input line seperated with space and input is ended with float 0 or EOF.

How to do this if i dont know how many numbers or in input, or how it works and ask to EOF if i am reading just numbers and not chars?

Thanks for any response.

example of input in one line:

```
12 11 10 45 50 12 EOF
12 10 11 45 0 

int main(void)  
{
    float num;
    float sum = 0;

    do{
       scanf("%f", num);
       sum += num;
    } while(EOF || num == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the manual page for `scanf` - It does return a value to be checked

Comment: Do you mean "literal string `"EOF"`"?

Comment: Unix like systems need you to type CTRL-D twice when you are not at the start of a line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [scanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets errno to EILSEQ.

So, you may rewrite your do-while loop to something like

```
int retval;
while((retval = scanf("%f", &num)) != EOF && retval > 0 && num != 0) {
    sum += num;
}

if(retval == 0) {
    printf("input read error.\n");
}
```

to match your constraints.

Also note you need to prefix your variable with `&` when passing it to `scanf()`, since the function expects a pointer to deal with (you need to pass variable address).

**EDIT:**

see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373386/eof-in-windows-command-prompt-doesnt-terminate-input-stream) concerning EOF problems in Windows

Comment: many of i want works but this didnt react on EOF(CTRL + D)
while(scanf(" %f", &num) != EOF && num != 0)

Comment: @user2899587 are you on windows?

Comment: yes, and if i pressed CTRL+D two times and then ENTER i cant write any more character

Comment: @user2899587 EOF under windows equals to CTRL+Z

Comment: still doesnt work ... same like CTRL+D, just it writes to console ^Z and dont go -_-

Comment: maybe it needs getchar() or something like this to combine with it

Comment: still dont work... thx for help. Maybe i have error in condition
int symbol;
float num;
while(symbol = scanf("%f", &num) != EOF || num != 0)

Comment: @user2899587 parenthesize your assignment, e.g., `while((symbol = scanf("%f", &num)) != EOF || num != 0)`

Comment: i just want to read nunmbers on input until 0 is there or EOF is pressed... but it didnt works maybe newline character condition? can you give me example on scanf? really thx

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of `scanf` -

> scanf returns the number of items successfully matched and assigned
>   which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an
>   early matching failure. The value EOF is returned if the end of input
>   is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching
>   failure occurs.

This means that scanf will return EOF only when it encounters EOF as the first input when it is called because **EOF must be preceded with a newline '\n' else it won't work (depending on the OS)**. You must also account for the matching failure `scanf` may encounter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float num;
    float sum = 0;
    int val;

    while((val = scanf("%f", &num)) != EOF && val == 1) {
        sum += num;
    }

    if(val == 0) {
        printf("matching failure. input is not a float.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("end of input.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: while((val = scanf("%f", &num)) != EOF && val == 1) it didnt works... can you give me example of input how use CTRL + D to work it

Comment: enter EOF by pressing ctrl + D, after pressing enter key, i.e., the first input in a line.

Comment: @user2899587 if you're on windows, EOF equals to CTRL+Z

Comment: Are not `while((val = scanf("%f", &num)) != EOF && val == 1)` and `while((val = scanf("%f", &num)) == 1)` the same?

Comment: @chux yes true, they are the same. Wrote it just for emphasizing  `EOF` at the cost of efficiency.

Comment: Suspect a good compiler would optimize out any inefficient so either approach could generate the same executable code.

Answer (score 0):

You can re write your code like this

```
         int main(void) 
         {
            float num;
            float sum = 0;
            do
            {
               scanf("%f", &num);
               sum += num;
            } while((!feof(stdin)) && (num != 0));

            printf("%f", sum);
            return 0;   

          }
```

Here feof indicates end of input stream.

Comment: This will give the wrong answer if the `scanf` conversion fails. The value in `num` will be the last successful value, and get added into the sum twice.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be a slightly more robust way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int sum=0;
  int num;
  char *p;
  char buf[1000];
  fgets(buf, 1000, stdin);
  p = strtok(buf," ");
  while(p!=NULL) {
    if(sscanf(p, "%d", &num) == 1) sum+=num;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  printf("the sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

Test:

```
> testme 
1 2 3 4 0

the sum is 10

> testme 
1 2 3 4 ^D
the sum is 10
```

Note - you have to enter `ctrl-D` *twice* to get the desired effect when you are at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your doubt clear by reading "C programming a modern approach by K N King"

This book provides proper clarification on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Test the result of `scanf()` for `0`, `1` or `EOF`.
Test the value scanned for `0.0`.

```
int main(void) {
  float num;
  float sum = 0;
  int cnt;

  while ((cnt = scanf("%f", &num)) == 1) {
    if (num == 0.0) break;
    sum += num;
  }

  // cnt should be EOF, 0 or 1      

  if (cnt == 0) {
    printf("Input is not a number\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Sum %f\n", sum);
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Although, in general, `scanf()` returns values EOF, 0, 1, ... "number of format specifiers", a value of 0 occurs rarely.  Example input is "+".

Comment: What if the very first `scanf` call fails due to matching failure? It would lead to undefined behaviour because `num` would contain garbage value.

Comment: @ajay Yes you are correct, saw that too and have corrected that.