# Inputting EOF notation when using getch() for standard input

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

here is a fragment of my program

```
     #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getch()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\t')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        else if (c == '\b')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        else if (c == '\\')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        else if (c == '\r')
        {
            puts("\\n");
          //  putchar('\n');
        }
        else{
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I want to terminate my input when I input EOF, but when I input ^Z I only get this:
[image]
so how can I input ^Z to terminate my input?

Comment: What's the type of `c`? It should be `int`. If it's `char`, then it can never be `EOF`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The code doesn't matter and is redundant, the question is more about the CMD terminal than the program in question. It's actually better suited to SuperUser.com

Comment: The EOF you're testing for in the `while` condition is not an EOF *character*, it's an actual end of file... or closed input stream, etc.

Comment: Found something related (I guess (-;): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373386/eof-in-windows-command-prompt-doesnt-terminate-input-stream

Comment: You can try `ctrl+D`

Comment: @sashoalm: Unless the problem is that `c` is the wrong type, which is one possible cause of the described symptoms.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal

Answer (score 3):

Your program works perfectly ... but `getch` does not do exactly what you expect.

`getch` (from conio.h) and `getchar` (from stdio.h) both get one character at a time, but not at same level. `getchar` is higher level, and so :

- reads on stdin (can be redirected)
- waits for a full buffer in line oriented mode
- is interrupted by a `Ctrl-C` (more exactly `Ctrl-C` is seen as a SIG_INT signal)
- translates special characters `Ctrl-D` on Unix-Linux `Ctrl-Z` on Windows as EOF

On the other hand, `getch` is low-level (and exists in Microsoft systems but is not standard C) :

- directly reads on the keyboard
- pass any character including `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-Z` as is
- the only possible interruption is via `Ctrl-Break`
- never returns EOF ( == -1)

All examples using `getch` works the same : **you** define what will be your end of input character and manually test it, there is no magical EOF.