# Why this code is resulting in an infinite loop?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    c=getchar();


    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c=getchar();
    }
}
```

Why this code is resulting in an infinite loop. It is from D.Ritchie's book.

Comment: What is `**EOF**` supposed to be?

Comment: How are you running it and giving it input?

Comment: Probably because your user never enters the EOF character?

Comment: It is Ctrl+Z on MS Windows console, and Ctrl+D on linux.

Comment: ... with ctrl+Z at least working only if the rest of that line is empty, if memory serves.

Comment: why ctrl-z doesn't work if not put after '\n'? I have read some explanation about this answer stating something about buffer. Please explain me what is buffer? I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It results in an infinite loop because `EOF` is not a character that can be entered via keyboard.

Take a look at this: [EOF in Windows command prompt doesn't terminate input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373386/eof-in-windows-command-prompt-doesnt-terminate-input-stream)

Comment: why ctrl-z doesn't work if not put after '\n'? I have read some explanation about this answer stating something about buffer. Please explain me what is buffer? I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this code in **Linux** after reading the last part of my answer ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    c=getchar();

    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c=getchar();
    }
    printf("\n %c  %d \n",c,c);

    return 0;
}
```

if you want to enter the `EOF` character you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> from the keyboard which is the end of file

you can see the last line in the output which refer to the character `EOF` with numeric value equals to `-1`

As a note `EOF` is a symbolic constant with value `-1` and you can see its definition in the header file `stdio.h`

```
#define EOF (-1)
```

Comment: Your main should return `int`.