# getchar and EOF C programming

Tags: c, windows, eof, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    }
}
```

This works fine, when EOF ( ctrl + z) is in a new line, but when the input
is :
blabla^z    
it does not work.
When i debug the program it tells me that the input "^z"(^z = EOF) is saved as 26,
but when the input ^z is in a new line it is saved as -1.
Why? 
in case something is unclear:
it is saved in the variable c, and does not work means it doesnt terminate the while loop, only when the input ^z is put in a new line it tearminates the loop 
im using windows

Comment: You forgot `#include <stdio.h>` in your code. Your question is probably operating system specific. On my Linux system CtrlZ is not related to EOF.

Comment: Try piping a file. Terminals behave sometimes strange due to line-buffering.

Comment: "does not work" is no **specific** problem description. Also " the input ^z is saved as 26" is not clear. Where is it saved? Which input?

Comment: it is saved in the variable c, and does not work means it doesnt terminate the while loop, only when the input ^z is put in a new line it tearminates the loop

Comment: You should rephrase the text in your question next time and just leave a comment that you updated. If that were not a dup, it would have been a good first question after the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using it wrong, and the CTRL+z symbol is not send to the getchar() function (which would give an EOF) but to the system that runs you program (e.g. it will "Stopped" the program).

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
// while ((c = getchar()) != '.') {
    putchar(c);
    }
    putchar('W');
}
```

Do you see the ouput 'W' in any case ? (especially when using a new line ?) in my case, I get "Stopped" (on UNix system, [CTRL+Z is used to suspend a process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z)).

[On Windows system, the answer has already been given on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373386/eof-in-windows-command-prompt-doesnt-terminate-input-stream):

> At the end of a line, hitting ^z (or ^d on linux) does not cause the
>   terminal driver to send EOF. It only makes it flush the buffer to your
>   process (with no \n).
>
> Hitting ^z (or ^d on linux) at the start of a line is interpreted by
>   the terminal as "I want to signal EOF".

Comment: Yea is see the output W (btw im using windows)

Comment: Well, after trying on windows, I get the same behaviour as yours.

Comment: Ok, actually it has been answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373386/eof-in-windows-command-prompt-doesnt-terminate-input-stream

Comment: In Windows shell, ^Z does not suspend the program