# Python script not running until i hit ctrl+C

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a simple Python3 program like below:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
print (tokens)
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
if ((a + b)> 18):
    print ("Input numbers should be between 0 and 9")
else:
    print(a + b)
```

but while running this like below:

```
C:\Python_Class>python APlusB.py
3 5<- pressed enter after this
```

but output is not coming until I hit ctrl+C (in windows)

```
C:\Python_Class>python APlusB.py
3 5
['3', '5']
8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "APlusB.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(a + b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: use the `input` function.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdin.read()` will read until an EOF (end of file) is encountered. That's why "pressing enter" doesn't seem to do anything. You can send an EOF on Windows by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or on *nix systems with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

(Note that you probably still need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> before hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I don't think the terminal treats the EOF correctly if it's not at the start of a line.)

If you just want to read input until a newline, use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead of `sys.stdin.read()`.

Comment: See this answer for a more detailed explanation about EOF behavior at the beginning of a new line vs other places in a line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373799/1427124

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `sys.stdin.read` attempts to read *all the data* that the standard input can provide, including new lines, spaces, tabs, *whatever*. It will stop reading only if the interpreter's interrupted or it hits an EndOfFile (Ctrl+D on UNIX-like systems and Ctrl+Z on Windows).

The standard function that asks for input is simply `input()`

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned using Windows, in which case Ctrl+D most likely does not result in EOF.

Answer (score 0):

you can read user's input using **input()** function.

### Example Code

```
user_input = input("Please input a number !")
# Rest of the code
```