# getchar example from K&R C does not work properly

Tags: c

I was wondering what's happening in this code from K&R C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar(); ++nc) {
        ;
    }
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

When I run the code (OS X El Capitan), the `for` loop doesn't finish and I can't get to the `printf` statement.

Comment: check out [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)

Comment: Are you terminating the input stream?

Comment: Yes I finish it with an enter

Comment: To clarify, your program is waiting for input.  If it is running with its stdin connected to a terminal, that means it is waiting for you to type something and close the stream (on *nix, with ctrl-d).  Try redirecting input from a file.  `./a.out < file.txt`

Comment: `enter` does not close the stream, it just writes a newline.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : that won't work - `getchar` will return `EOF` when reaching the end of the stream, which is negative and won't end the loop. You need to have a `'\0'` character on the stream to end the loop.

Comment: Is that the only solution? What happened on the bigger programs of the industry that use C?

Comment: That code is not from K&R - the original example uses `long nc` and tests for `EOF`.

Comment: @egarro: you can check all the open-source projects. note: reading a *single* character is quite rare in practice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with example 1.5.2 in K&R book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646255/problem-with-example-1-5-2-in-kr-book-on-c)

Comment: Please, can somebody help me with the right solution?

Comment: @Paul R This code is from: C The Programming Language second edition

Comment: @egarro: you combine a posted answer with the comments above, and you have a solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getchar()` returns the obtained character on success or `EOF` on failure. Reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar).

Try this

```
for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) { }
```

Note that, <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't means `EOF`, it means newline or `'\n'`.

Look at the header `stdio.h`, says,

```
#define EOF (-1)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof) you can see how to simulate an EOF.

```
Windows: Ctrl+Z
Unix :   Ctrl+D
```

So long story short, you can put any condition in the `for` loop, like

```
for (nc = 0; getchar() != '\n'; ++nc) { } // break the loop if enter pressed
for (nc = 0; getchar() != 'c'; ++nc) { } // break the loop if c pressed
.
.
.
```

Comment: This needs a semicolon or an empty block like `for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) {}` which is actually better  than the semicolon.

Comment: @egarro, I added some more information for you, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` waits on the input from stdin and even if you enter any character it would be read by `getchar()` but that doesn't make you get out of the loop.

So you need to add some condition on the return value of `getchar()` to gracefully exit the loop.

For Eg:

```
for(;getchar() != EOF;)
{
}
```

If you want to return on newline character then check should be `getchar() != '\n'`

PS: I have just shown how to check the return value , for me the exit condition is `EOF` it might vary for you.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath To avoid confusion I got rid of it

Comment: egarro If it still "is not working", you are probably ignoring the advice to close the input stream.

Comment: What's the difference between EOF and "\n"?

Comment: @egarro: what's the difference between the end of the file and end of the line? pretty much everything...

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for (nc = 0; getchar(); ++nc) {
        ;
```

will iterate until getchar() returns 0. To achieve this without rewritting the program as others are suggesting you should for example in Windows press key combination `Ctrl + @` and then press Enter. The value of key combination `Ctrl + @` is equal to 0.

Comment: or eg. `echo -e "foo\0" | ./a.out` on linux

Answer (score 0):

If you revise your code to make it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double nc;

    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++nc;
    }

    printf("\n%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Then if you run it in a terminal window and enter the following:

abcCtrl-D

you will get the output:

abc
3

(The Ctrl-D is the EOF character)

Comment: "The Ctrl-D is the EOF character" .. for Unix. Not for Windows. Why type twice? Why did you change the type of nc?

Comment: Olaf - the questioner is using OS X, I assume in a terminal window, but I admit I might be wrong about that.

Comment: It is just if Windows-unsers read that; this might trigger another unecessary complaint. However, I removed the downvote, as my major concern was the changed type - I completely understand, actually; had to check myself first if that is actually allowed for float types.